# How to apply multivariate normal pdf function in Python with my own data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I use the following code to produce random data and plot the distribution of probability densities. How can I do the same with my own data as shown below?

Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

mean, cov = [0, 1], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["X", "Y"])
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 1000).T

g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, data=df, kind="kde", n_levels=75, color="m")
g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c="black", s=30, linewidth=1, marker="+")
g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)
g.set_axis_labels("X", "Y");
```

My own data sample

```
        X       Y
0       1       8
1       7       8
2       7       9
3       5       8
4       7       7
5       9       9
6       1       3
4       6       8
5       9       7
6       9       6
7       8       2
8       1       9
9       0       10
10      22      2
11      4       45
12      9       8
```

I tried this but I am getting strange values

```
import numpy as np

mean = np.mean(data1['X'], axis=0)
cov = np.cov(data1['Y'], rowvar=0)
X = multivariate_normal.pdf(data1['X'], mean=2.5, cov=0.5)

mean = np.mean(data1['X'], axis=0)
cov = np.cov(data1['Y'], rowvar=0)
Y = multivariate_normal.pdf(data1['Y'], mean=2.5, cov=0.5)

df = np.concatenate( (X.reshape(-1,1),Y.reshape(-1,1)) , axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df =  df.rename({0: 'X', 1: 'Y'}, axis=1) 

g = sns.jointplot(x=X, y=Y, data=df, kind="kde", n_levels=75, color="r")
g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c="black", s=30, linewidth=1, marker="+")
g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)
g.set_axis_labels("X", "Y");
```

Comment: Replace the assignment of x, y with lists of your custom data, preferably in separate lines.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but something is wrong. I am getting weird values.

Comment: Okay, I think code is working.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked.

```
import numpy as np

mean = np.mean(data1['X'], axis=0)
cov = np.cov(data1['Y'], rowvar=0)
X = multivariate_normal.pdf(data1['X'], mean=2.5, cov=0.5)

mean = np.mean(data1['X'], axis=0)
cov = np.cov(data1['Y'], rowvar=0)
Y = multivariate_normal.pdf(data1['Y'], mean=2.5, cov=0.5)

df = np.concatenate( (X.reshape(-1,1),Y.reshape(-1,1)) , axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df =  df.rename({0: 'X', 1: 'Y'}, axis=1) 

g = sns.jointplot(x=X, y=Y, data=df, kind="kde", n_levels=75, color="r")
g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c="black", s=30, linewidth=1, marker="+")
g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)
g.set_axis_labels("X", "Y");
```